# Laravel Eloquent - Query with a dynamic number of WHERE() conditions

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a table of 2 columns, `property_id` and `amenity_id`. The relation ship is many to many.

So I have a dynamic array of values `$input['property_amenities']` and I want to find all `property_id` keys that have ALL values in the array.

So far I'm using the `whereIn()` method but that gets the union (like OR) of each query but I need the AND of these conditions.

So each property_id returned should contain every value in the input array.

I want something like this, but this doesn't work.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($input['property_amenities']); $i++) {
     $propertieswithAmenities = $propertieswithAmenities- 
      >where('amenity_id', '=',$input['property_amenities'][$i]);
 }
 return $propertywithAmenities->get();
```

Comment: Try
propertieswithAmenities::whereIn('amenity_id', collect($input['property_amenities'])->flatten()->all())->get();

Comment: `whereIn` with an `!empty` would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Here it will check the data of array with only one query and no need to add any loop. Hope it can help you.

```
$propertieswithAmenities::whereIn('amenity_id', collect($input['property_amenities'])->flatten()->all())->get();
```